# How to move by columns in an org table?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

The title pretty much says it all.  I'm looking for something similar to `M-f` and `M-b` to move right or left column-wise in an `org-mode` table.

Comment: According to the [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Built_002din-table-editor.html#Built_002din-table-editor), `tab` and `S-tab` run `org-table-next-field` and `org-table-previous-field`.